# How can I make eyelashes and eyebrows to follow rigged mesh to work after reconecting all

Tags: rigging, particles, hair

I have created and rigged my character. I disconected eyelashes and eyebrows before parenting the rig to de mesh. [image]. As you can see the are still in place.

After I connect all again nothing happens, It doesn't follow the movements of the rigged mesh but when I check the "user modifier stack" they  are not in place anymore, they dissapear or are located somewhere else where they should be.

[image]

This is what happen when I apply (CTRL+A) Rotation & Scale (picture 3)
[image]

How can I fix/solve this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if the particles modifier is after the armature modifier in the modifiers stack. Apply (Ctrl A) all rot and scale, both to meshes and rig.

Comment: This is what happen after I apply (CTRL+A) Rotation & Scale => picture 3